# I need a USB Bluetooth Hub with a decent range

Tags: usb, bluetooth, hub, bluetooth-adapter

I need a USB Bluetooth Hub that has a range of at least 30 feet.  It should have low latency, at least 3 USB ports, little to no loss of input, and should have great quality with a decent price.  The most I'll pay for is 30$ and I prefer it be on amazon although not needed.  I intend to use this to connect a wired mouse and keyboard to my computer wirelessly.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question properly you are looking for a USB hub wich connects to the computer through Bluetooh instead of using a cable, am I right?

In that case such a thing does not exists because Bluetooth is a very slow protocol and would not be USB compliant, not only because of the speed but because of the lattency, causing devices to disconnect intermitently.

I think it would be easier to get a good bluetooth adapter with a bluetooth Keyboard and mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Tp-link bluetooth 20$, 65ft range.

TP-Link USB Bluetooth Adapter for PC(UB400).
Support Windows 10/8.1/8/7/XP for Desktop, Laptop, Mouse, Keyboard, Printers, Headsets, Speakers, PS4/ Xbox Controllers

Comment: Welcome to Hardware Recs! I believe the OP is asking about a USB hub that can connect over Bluetooth, not a USB Bluetooth dongle.